# If not empty jump to somewhere in PS

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Hello and good morning(:

I'm looking to see if I'm able to jump to somewhere in PS without wrapping it in a ScriptBlock; hell, I'd  even be okay with that but, I'm just unsure on how to go about it.

What I'm trying to do is: add a Parameter Set to a function and if something is supplied to the parameter `-GrpSelec`(I know imma change it), then just skip the rest of the script and go to my `$swap` variable to perform the switch.

```
$Group1 = @("1st Group", "2nd Group")
$Group2 = @("3rd Group", "4th Group")

Function Test-Group{
    param(
        [ValidateSet("Group1","group2")]
        [array]$GrpSelec)
if($GrpSelec){ &$swap }

$AllGroups = @("Group1", "Group2")

for($i=0; $i -lt $AllGroups.Count; $i++){
    Write-Host "$($i): $($AllGroups[$i])"}

$GrpSelec = Read-Host -Prompt "Select Group(s)" 
$GrpSelec = $GrpSelec -split " "
$swap = Switch -Exact ($GrpSelec){            
            {1 -or "Group1"}  {"$Group1"}
            {2 -or "Group2"}  {"$Group2"}
            }

Foreach($Group in $swap){
    "$Group"}
        
    }
```

Is something like this even possible?

I've googled a couple of similar questions which point to the invocation operator `&`(as shown above), and/or, a `foreach` which is definitely not the same lol.

*take it easy on me, im just experimenting(:*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simple `if` statement?

```
function Test-Group {
  param(
    [string[]]$GrpSelec
  )

  if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('GrpSelect')){
    # no argument was passed to -GrpSelec, 
    # populate $GrpSelec in here before proceeding with the rest of the script
  }

  # Now that $GrpSelec has been populated, let's do the work
  $swap = Switch -Exact ($GrpSelec){            
            {1 -or "Group1"}  {"$Group1"}
            {2 -or "Group2"}  {"$Group2"}
          }

  # rest of function
}
```

Comment: I think my issue is trying to make a selection out of the `$AllGroups` array. I attempted to incorporate your suggestion but, even after i provide a value to the parameter, it still prompts me for a selection of the 2 groups.

Comment: **GrpSelec** and **GrpSelect**

Comment: @notjustme thank you for that, i didn't notice it! Now im just having an issue where its printing out both array even if i just call one

Comment: will post a separate question for that on monday